# Representing the difference between time_t

Tags: c++, time-t

Why is the difference between two `time_t`s returned by the `difftime( time_t t1, time_t t2)` method as a `double`? I don't see where the precision requirement comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `time_t` is simply defined in the standard as an `arithmetic type capable of representing times`.

That's about all it says about it. It doesn't have to be an integer, it doesn't have to represent seconds. It could only ever be a multiple of ten or it may be a floating point type capable of representing times down to a resolution of 10<sup>-43</sup> seconds.

The quote from `C99 7.23.1 Components of time` is (slightly paraphrased):

> Types declared are `clock_t` and `time_t`, which are arithmetic types capable of representing times. The range and precision of times representable in clock_t and time_t are implementation-defined.

Hence people who blindly work out the time difference with:

```
delta = time_end - time_begin;
```

may find that their code doesn't work on all platforms.

Now I don't know off the top of my head any platforms where it's not a simple seconds since the epoch but I've been bitten by assumptions *like* this before, such as assuming `A` through `Z` are contiguous whereas, in fact, that is not required and doesn't work so well on the mainframe products which use EBCDIC. And, yes, they're [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82915/any-other-mainframers-here/121002#121002) in *heavy* use despite apparently having been dying since the '60s :-)

The C99 rationale document has this to say:

> The types `clock_t` and `time_t` are arithmetic because values of these types must, in accordance with existing practice, on occasion be compared with -1 (a "don’t-know" indication), suitably cast.
>
> No arithmetic properties of these types are defined by the Standard, however, in order to allow implementations the maximum flexibility in choosing ranges, precisions, and representations most appropriate to their intended application. The representation need not be a count of some basic unit; an implementation might conceivably represent different components of a temporal value as subfields of an integer type.

Comment: Technically you're right about the portability, but do you happen to know any platforms where time_t does not work as most are accustomed to?

Comment: @John, not off the top of my head (see the update) but I'd still prefer to code for portability as much as practicable.

Comment: I'm all for portability--I was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Despite being universally thought of — and implemented — as an integral type representing seconds since the beginning of some epoch, `time_t` is not actually formally defined as such, so you couldn't portably make use the result of difftime if it was a `time_t`. As for other alternatives: `int` is too small in some circumstances (as is `long`) and `long long` isn't portable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it is the most general arithmetic type.  And it allows better than second precision if the underlying `time_t` supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that there are no arithmetic operations defined for the type `time_t`, by returning a double it implies that you can use the result in calculations.

IOW if you add two `time_t` values with each other you are in unsafe territory since different behavior could result if time_t is defined as an unsigned int or a normal int - depending on your platform.